# Cannot loop through array comparing text values, undefined result with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I am new to protractor and JavaScript and struggling trying to compare a delimited string to an array.

What I am trying to do is to find a list of all elements and then from each element, loop through the arrays to compare the text values to the delimited string but the delimited string values are 'undefined'

```
element.all(by.css('.itemField')).then(function (allFieldItems) {
  var  toCompare= ["AGO", "9"]
  for (var i = 0; i < toCompare.length; i++) {
    var valueToCompare = toCompare[i]
    allFieldItems[i].getText().then(function (text) {
      if(text != valueToCompare[i]){
        console.log("Values don't match")
          }
        }.bind( i))
      }
})
```

The problem is that the line "if(text != valueToCompare[i]) the "valueToCompare[i]" is always 'undefined' and I am looking for help on how to  resolve this without using expect statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `getText()` on the result of `element.all()` directly:

```
var toCompare = ["AGO", "9"];
element.all(by.css('.itemField')).getText().then(function (texts) {
    for (var i = 0; i < toCompare.length; i++) {  
        if (texts[i] != toCompare[i]) { 
            console.log("Values don't match");
        } 
    }
});
```

Or, you may even expect it like this (not sure if this is what you are actually trying to do):

```
expect($$('.itemField').getText()).toEqual(toCompare);
```